# How to Display images horizontally in html

Tags: php, html, css

I need to display the images horizontaly. All the images are fetching from admin panel. Here is the code, But here all the images are displaying vertically.

```
<div class="portfolioimages"><img src="image.png"/></div>
<div class="portfolioimages"><img src="image1.png"/></div>
<div class="portfolioimages"><img src="image2.png"/></div>
<div class="portfolioimages"><img src="image3.png"/></div>
<div class="portfolioimages"><img src="image4.png"/></div>
<div class="portfolioimages"><img src="image5.png"/></div>
<div class="portfolioimages"><img src="image6.png"/></div>
<div class="portfolioimages"><img src="image7.png"/></div>
<div class="portfolioimages"><img src="image8.png"/></div>
```

Here is the fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/2wzh1mk7/

```
<?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
            <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>          
                <div class="blog1">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/blogimages/thumbs/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" class="testimonials1"/>

                </div>

            <?php endforeach ;endif;?>
```

This is my actual code in php for the clarification i have written in html form. If i give style as display:inline all the images will display in sinlge row but i need to display 3 images in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you need to set `float: Left` Property on div class.

```
.portfolioimages{
  float:left;
}
```

Use counter variable and check. Please check below code for 3 images per row.

```
<?php 
$cnt = 1;
if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
<?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>          
    <div class="blog1">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/images/blogimages/thumbs/<?php echo $r->image_path;?>" class="testimonials1"/>

    </div>

<?php 
if(($cnt%3) == 0) { echo "<br>"; }
$cnt++;
endforeach ;endif;?>
```

Comment: I need to display three images in a row but if i give float : left then all will be shown in single row.

Comment: No it is displaying the images one by one only

Comment: displaying 2 in a row  i need to display 3

Comment: Another way to take key with foreach loop `<?php foreach ($records2 as $key=>$r):?>` and then check for 3 row `<?php if(($key%3) == 0) { echo "<br>"; } ?>`

Comment: Ok, Just put $cnt++ after the if code completed. `<?php if(($cnt%3) == 0) { echo "<br>"; } $cnt++; ?>` @user7047368

Comment: No it is displaying 2 only per row

Comment: adding break tag after 2 images only

Comment: Its because of $cnt is 0 please make it 1. Like `$cnt=1`. @user7047368

Comment: Atleast give your feedback with accept answer. @user7047368

Comment: Check this one and let me know where you are facing issue: https://eval.in/664245 @user7047368

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)

Comment: I have used braces rather then : colon. :)

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying

Comment: you are using `foreach :` with `:` colon and in my demo code i have used `foreach {` with braces. Hope you will get what I am telling. You can define foreach with both ways. :)

Comment: but not getting it is displaying only 2 per row

Comment: If i am trying with brackets getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH)

Comment: are you new to PHP or you are not able to judge the PHP errors?

Comment: I am giving you working example demo then also you are saying its not working :) Live demo: http://eval.in/664245

Comment: The code which you gave i tried with that code only totally but also it is displaying two only same code just copied and pasted

Comment: I think it is because of css getting more space after the images

Answer (score 3):

Try following style

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.portfolioimages {
display:inline;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
<div class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ashwini Patil it will display all the images in a single row but i need to display 3 three images in a row

Comment: Ok. If you want 3 images in a single row, then you can use <br> tag after every three images.

Comment: Those images are coming are fetching from backend this is not static page.PLease go through my updated code

Answer (score 1):

The default "display" style property for DIV is "block". Set it to "inline" or "inline-block" in CSS:

```
<style> div { display: inline; }</style>
```

P.S.: This is not a PHP question, this is a CSS question.

Comment: As i have mentioned php it is correct .In the description i have mentioned as all the images are fetching from admin panel and displaying the front end.

Comment: You need to either insert a stylesheet or change the output of the admin panel to add the inline style as shown in @Ruchish Parikh's answer

Answer (score 1):

FLEX solution:

```
<div class="box">
  <div> element you want </div>
  <div> element you want </div>
  <div> element you want </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.box{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<div style="display:inline;" class="portfolioimages">AAAA</div>
```

Note: Added `display:inline`

Comment: I need to display three images per row.if we give display:inline means all the images will been displayed in single row.

Comment: So you already have the answer. if you use `<div>` with `display: block` you can get vertical divs. You can add 3 divs inside a `div` and make the child divs as `display: inline`

Answer (score 0):

Please tag right topic for question, This is related to CSS and use  below css

```
<style>
div {  
  display:inline;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

### This is working please check it

.portfolioimages{float:left}